# Unable to use `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` with `matplotlib.pyplot,plot_surface`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I tried building a minimal example to reproduce a problem I was having. Please ignore the randomly generated data arrays `x` and `y`. I am feeding perfectly meaningful data into the `zSpline` call inside `plot_surface`. You could try replacing the penultimate line with - `surf=ax.plot_surface(xg,yg,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0.1)` where I have replaced the ZSpline with the coarse data `z`. This works which indicates to me that I am not mistaken on syntax.

My code is-

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

size=21
dat = np.random.randn(size, 2)
x=dat[:,0]
y=dat[:,1]
z=np.random.randn(size//3,size//3)
i=np.tile([1,2,3],size//3)
bool_dat=(i==1)
x_new=x[bool_dat]
y_new=y[bool_dat]
xi=np.linspace(x_new.min(),x_new.max(),size//3)
yi=np.linspace(y_new.min(),y_new.max(),size//3)

#print z.shape,xi.shape,yi.shape

zSpline = RectBivariateSpline(xi,yi,z)

xg,yg = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
print zSpline(xg,yg)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(xg,yg,zSpline(xg,yg),rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0.1)
plt.show()
```

The error I get is -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a98e6c15985e> in <module>()
     22 
     23 xg,yg = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
---> 24 print zSpline(xg,yg)
     25 fig=plt.figure()
     26 ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, mth)
    671             z,ier = dfitpack.bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y)
    672             if not ier == 0:
--> 673                 raise ValueError("Error code returned by bispev: %s" % ier)
    674             return z
    675         raise NotImplementedError('unknown method mth=%s' % mth)

ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

Which leads me to believe that problem is with the interpolation routine and not the data/syntax. Any suggestions on how to test this further?

EDIT: In response to the comment that tells me that the problem is probably from the type of data, I decided to test with non-random data. the following code is almost the same as the first one - but I will paste it again anyway.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

size=21
xi=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,size)
yi=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,size)

xg,yg = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
z=np.sin(xg)*np.sin(yg) #nice and smooth function
zSpline = RectBivariateSpline(xi,yi,z,kx=2,ky=2)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf=ax.plot_surface(xg,yg,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0.1)
#surf=ax.plot_surface(xg,yg,zSpline(xg,yg),rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0.1)
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following image as output.
[image: plot with coarse data]
However if the zSpline is used, an error is raised.

EDIT2:
The issue resolves itself if I use `xg,yg = np.ogrid[-np.pi:np.pi:size*1j,-np.pi:np.pi:size*1j]` instead of meshgrid. But I still do not know why!

Comment: An [error code of 10 means "invalid input data (see restrictions)"](http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/bispev.f). (maybe that helps a tiny bit)

Comment: is it possible to probe how the data is invalid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.__call__.html).

The issue is that xg and yg you give to the spline are 2D arrays, but the routine expects them to be 1D arrays that define the grid (i.e. `xi,yi`).

Comment: That was my first guess, but no `ValueError` was raised.

Comment: That a `ValueError` was not raised but you get a different error doesn't really mean anything. The documentation here is correct.

Comment: The `mgrid` version worked earlier without the spline. You are definitely right according to the documentation though.